# Rails mysql: How to query tables with deeply nested relations(has_many and belongs_to)?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :keys
end

class Key < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building
end

class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Has column "name"
end
```

I want to get all users that have keys that belong to a building with the name "HQ"

Bassicaly something like this(pseudo query):

```
Users = users.where('keys.room.building.name=?', name)
```

This is the furthest I got:

```
users = User.joins(:keys).where('keys.room.building.name=?', name)
```

But it gives the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.name='HQ')' at line 1: 
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `keys` ON `keys`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE (keys.room.building.name='HQ')):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot

```
User.joins(keys: [room: :building]).where("buildings.name" => name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
User.joins(:keys => {:room => {:building}}).where("buildings.name" => name)
```

Assuming you also want to eager load avoid 1+N queries:

```
User.includes(:keys => {:room => {:building}}).where("buildings.name" => name)
```

Hope this is useful to you!!

Comment: Hi, what's the difference between "User.joins(:keys => {:room => {:building}})" and lusketeer's anwser: "User.joins(keys: [room: :building])"?

Comment: @MeesterPatat take a look at this article [includes vs joins](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html)

Comment: I meant what is the difference between using curly brackets and square brackets.